# ViewPager: recovering from configuration change

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I'm having a really hard time to recover from configuration changes with `ViewPager`.

What I want is save the current pager position so that after a config change the same page will be visible. To do that, I save `pager.getCurrentItem()` and restore it using `pager.setCurrentItem`. Just that this doesn't work: `setCurrentItem` actually attempts to recreate that page instead of selecting it! And that's even though the page has already been created.

Now I'm not sure if I missed something when implementing the adapter that's backing it, but is there a pitfall to `setCurrentItem` and when `ViewPager` thinks that it's fully constructed? Looking at the code of that function though, it makes no sense to me; it seems to always try to recreate a page, except when there are no items at all:

```
void setCurrentItemInternal(int item, boolean smoothScroll, boolean always, int velocity) {
    // these are the only checked that make this method return
    if (mAdapter == null || mAdapter.getCount() <= 0) {
        setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
        return;
    }
    if (!always && mCurItem == item && mItems.size() != 0) {
        setScrollingCacheEnabled(false);
        return;
    }

    // ... removed some init code

    mCurItem = item;
    populate();

    // ...
}
```

As you can see, `populate()` is always called, except when there are either no items at all, or the item you're trying to select was already selected. What gives? That doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> setCurrentItem actually attempts to recreate that page instead of selecting it! And that's even though the page has already been created.

Not exactly, at least in terms of how I read the code.

> As you can see, populate() is always called, except when there are either no items at all, or the item you're trying to select was already selected.

`populate()` will call `addNewItem()`, which calls `instantiateItem()` on the `PagerAdapter`. The `FragmentPagerAdapter` implementation of `PagerAdapter` will use an existing fragment if available, otherwise it calls out to `getItem()` so you create the page yourself. So, if you use `setRetainInstance(true)` with your page fragments, and you are using `FragmentPagerAdapter`, they should be reused.

`FragmentStatePagerAdapter` seems more complicated, and if you are rolling your own `PagerAdapter` sans fragments, it is up to you to implement a caching mechanism.

Comment: Hi Mark, I'm not using `FragmentPagerAdapter`. Does that mean I can not rely on `instantiateObject` being only called when necessary, i.e. have to cache these instances myself?

Comment: @Matthias: `ViewPager` will cache stuff itself based on `setOffscreenPageLimit()`, but AFAIK that does not get used on orientation changes. Any caching beyond that (or recycling) is up to the `PagerAdapter` implementation.

Comment: Thanks--I'm simply caching the view instances returned from the factory method now, which does the job. However, I still think it's a flaw in the system that `instantiateItem` is called twice for every page, once during layout phase, and then again in `setCurrentItem`. I can't imagine this is on purpose, makes no sense at all.

Comment: @Matthias: As most open source projects say, contributions are welcome. :-)